# Protected inline method in parent class can't access other protected methods

Tags: kotlin, inline, access-modifiers

I am having a problem getting **IllegalAccessError** for the following example:

I have a base class declared in a gradle module called `arch`

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    protected abstract val value: Int

    fun run() {
        Log.d("Printme", "value $value")
    }

    protected inline fun getMyValue(): Lazy<Int> = lazy {
        getAnEight()
    }

    protected fun getAnEight() = 8
}
```

and a child class declared in gradle module called `app`

```
class ChildClass: BaseClass() {
    override val value by getMyValue()
}
```

It is worth saying I am creating a Kotlin project using Android Studio, but these classes are all simple Kotlin objects without any Android specific references. Of course these two modules also have different packages.

Now, from my main entry method I am doing the following (inside `app` module)

```
ChildClass().run()
```

I am calling my `run()` method declared in base class, which is accessing lazy initiated `value` property, which is in turn calling `getAnEight()` method. Since all methods are protected I would expect there is no reason a child class can't call all these. Even if one of the methods is marked as `inline` and this call gets replaced with method contents, it should still be able to call `getAnEight()` just fine.

Instead I am receiving `IllegalAccessError` saying `BaseClass.getAnEight() is inaccessible to class ChildClass$$special$$inlined$getMeValue$1`. This problem disappears when I remove `inline` modifier, or if I place `BaseClass` in the same package as `ChildClass`.

Is this a bug in Kotlin compiler? Or can someone explain to me this behavior if it's working as intended? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#public-inline-restrictions

> When an inline function is public or protected and is not a part of a
>   private or internal declaration, it is considered a module's public
>   API. It can be called in other modules and is inlined at such call
>   sites as well.
>
> This imposes certain risks of binary incompatibility caused by changes
>   in the module that declares an inline function in case the calling
>   module is not re-compiled after the change.
>
> To eliminate the risk of such incompatibility being introduced by a
>   change in non-public API of a module, the public API inline functions
>   are not allowed to use non-public-API declarations, i.e. private and
>   internal declarations and their parts, in their bodies.
>
> An internal declaration can be annotated with @PublishedApi, which
>   allows its use in public API inline functions. When an internal inline
>   function is marked as @PublishedApi, its body is checked too, as if it
>   were public.

EDIT: I made some bytecode research. The problem is that protected getMyValue() function is inlined **into public constructor**. In decompiled bytecode, ChildClass public constructor has a following line:

```
Lazy var4 = LazyKt.lazy((Function0)(new ChildClass$$special$$inlined$getMyValue$1(this)));
```

As you can see, it creates an instance of class `ChildClass$$special$$inlined$getMyValue$1`. Let's look at its declaration:

```
public final class ChildClass$$special$$inlined$getMyValue$1 extends Lambda implements Function0 {

    final BaseClass this$0;

    public ChildClass$$special$$inlined$getMyValue$1(BaseClass var1) {
        super(0);
        this.this$0 = var1;
    }

    public Object invoke() {
        return this.invoke();
    }

    public final int invoke() {
        return this.this$0.getAnEight(); // Here lies the problem
    }
}
```

When you create a ChildClass instance, its constructor only creates a `ChildClass$$special$$inlined$getMyValue$1` instance, that does not throw any errors. But when you call run(), `invoke()` method of class above is called. This method is public, its class is public, constructor was public, but getAnEight method is protected. That's how we get this error.

Comment: I have studied this section of documentation but have failed to understand it properly. It says that: public API inline functions (so marked with public or protected) can't use non-public API declarations (so private and internal). But given that definition, my protected (so public API) function is accessing another protected (so public API) function. So I think I am not doing anything that is prohibited here.

Comment: Extended my answer with some bytecode research, may be it will make the problem more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the extended research. Of course when we look at this it makes sense. So now we have to face a basic question - is this a bug in Kotlin compiler or not? Obviously an error appears because Kotlin code was translated into Java bytecode this way. Question is - maybe it's wrong and it should have been compiled in a way that allows the things I am trying to do?

Comment: Well, this *may* be a bug, but in your case you just don't really need that inline modifier.

Comment: Well, it IS a bug. There are issues about this problem already: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22625 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27441

Comment: I don't need it in this example, sure, but that's only because I simplified my real use-case that does need it :) Anyway, the issue you linked seems to be exactly what I am facing. Thanks a lot!